# How can I send info.fileList[0].originFileObj in ant design(typescript) with form data to server?

Tags: typescript, file-upload, react-hooks, antd

I need to send form data to the server but I have a type error, and also form date is empty!!!!

[image]

```html
export interface RcFile extends File {
  uid: string;
  readonly lastModifiedDate: Date;
  readonly webkitRelativePath: string;
}

interface File extends Blob {
  readonly lastModified: number;
  readonly name: string;
}

interface Blob {
  readonly size: number;
  readonly type: string;
  arrayBuffer(): Promise<ArrayBuffer>;
  slice(start?: number, end?: number, contentType?: string): Blob;
  stream(): ReadableStream;
  text(): Promise<string>;
}

export interface UploadChangeParam<T extends object = UploadFile> {
  file: T;
  fileList: Array<UploadFile>;
  event?: {
      percent: number;
  };
}
export const FileUpload: React.FunctionComponent<{}> = () => {
  const [defaultFileList, setDefaultFileList] = useState<Array<UploadFile>>([])

  const handleOnChange = (info: UploadChangeParam) => {
    setDefaultFileList(info.fileList)
    const finalData = info.fileList[0].originFileObj
    const formData = new FormData()
    formData.append(name, finalData)
    console.log('formData', formData)
  }



  useEffect(() => { console.log('useEffectFileUpload') }, [])

  return (
    <div className="upload-file">
      <Upload onChange={handleOnChange}>
        {defaultFileList.length >= 1 ? null : (
          <Row>
            <Text.Small>  Upload File</Text.Small>
            <Button colour="white" icon={'upload'}> Select file</Button>
          </Row>
        )}
      </Upload>
    </div>
  )
}
export default FileUpload
```

I am going send file upload date (in ant design with typescript ), I have got Error

```html
The argument of type 'File | Blob | undefined' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string | Blob'.
  Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'string | Blob'.ts(2345)
```

My question is How can I send formdate i need to support ant design and typescript support
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ynfzY.png)

Answer (score 2):

I used a slightly different approach (using a form), but converting the originFileObj to a blobl did the trick for me

```
formData.append('file', fileList[0].originFileObj as Blob);
```